# is it possible to run a selenium test using multiple different browsers at once?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, automated-tests, testng

I have a suite of tests that involve multiple users logging into a service. We are currently using selenium grid to allow up to 5 sessions being run at once for Firefox and Chrome, however we can only run 1 Internet Explorer session.

one workaround is to create multiple VMs but that's not ideal.

Ultimately I'd like to be able to run multiple IE sessions at once but the preferred solution for now is to use multiple browsers at once.

So:

```
User A logs into IE8
User B logs into Chrome
User C logs into Firefox
user A communicates with User B&C
```

is that doable as a feature file?  is TestNg the way to go here?  we are currently using JUnit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...however we can only run 1 Internet Explorer session

You can configure this yourself.  In your `nodeConfig.json` file, specify something like:

```
{
  "capabilities":
    [
      {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "version": "3.6",
        "platform": "WINDOWS",
        "maxInstances": 5
      },
      {
        "browserName": "internet explorer",
        "version": "8",
        "platform": "WINDOWS",
        "maxInstances": 5
      }
    ],
    "configuration": {
      "nodeTimeout":120,
      "port":5555,

      "hubPort":4444,
      "hubHost":"localhost",

      "nodePolling":2000,

      "registerCycle":10000,
      "register":true,
      "cleanUpCycle":2000,
      "timeout":30000,
      "maxSession":XXXXX,
    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed the max instances of IE to 5 but it still only ever launches one browser....

Comment: did you also change the maxSession?  This matters as well